# How to grab substring which meets certain requirements in python?

Tags: python

I have a python string that consists of "0", "1" and "x". I would to know what is the bit location of x in the string. eg. string1= '0100xx11xxx0x1' and the output is [(4,5),(8,10),(12)]. x appears in bit locations 4 to 5, locations 8 to 10, and location 12. The following scripts are written in python; however, the results are not really as expected.

```
string1= '0100xx11xxx0x1'
temparray=[]
trackarray=[]

i=0
for x in string1:
    if x=="x":
        #print('i: ',i)
        temparray.append(i)
        i=i+1
    else:
        if len(temparray)>1:
            bitsRange= (temparray[0],temparray[-1])

            trackarray.append(bitsRange)
            temparray=[]                          
        i=i+1            

print(trackarray)
```

Comment: You could use a regular expression to find all matches of 'x+'.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the solution using `regex`:

```
import re
string1= '0100xx11xxx0x1'
matches = []
for match in re.finditer(r'x+',string1): # iterates over re.Match object
    if match.start() == match.end()-1: matches.append(tuple([match.start()])) # if you want tuple else remove tuple() and []
    else: matches.append((match.start(), match.end()-1))
print(matches)
```

Here's a fix to your code:

```
string1= '0100xx11xxx0x1'
temparray=[]
trackarray=[]
i = 0
for x in string1:
    if x == "x":
        temparray.append(i)        
    elif len(temparray) > 1:
        trackarray.append((temparray[0],temparray[-1]))
        temparray = []
    elif len(temparray) == 1:
        trackarray.append(tuple(temparray)) # if you want in tuple else remove tuple()
        temparray = []
    i += 1        

print(trackarray)
```

**What did I fix?**
You  were just checking if the `len` is greater than `1`. However, when there is one value i.e `12` the length is one. So, I simply added support for that.

Docs:
[re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

Answer (score 0):

**Edited**:

```py
string1= '0100xx11xxx0x1'

temparray=[]
trackarray=[]

# ------------------ modified ------------------
for i, x in enumerate(string1):
    if x == 'x':
        temparray.append(i)
        continue
    
    if len(temparray) > 1:
        trackarray.append((temparray[0], temparray[-1]))
        temparray = []
    elif len(temparray) == 1:
        trackarray.append((temparray[0],))
        temparray = []

if len(temparray) == 1:
    trackarray.append((temparray[0],))
elif len(temparray) > 1:
    trackarray.append((temparray[0], temparray[-1]))
# ----------------------------------------------

print(trackarray)
# [(4, 5), (8, 10), (12,)]
```

Comment: Why do you first want to run `else` and then check if the length is greater. This just makes the code more complex for no reason. Also, you could totally remove the `bitsRange` as it is not needed.

Comment: Oh well haha yeah this code is just for the moment. I just intended to modify as little code as I can so that he/she could understand modified code more straightforwardly :) Yes your answer seems to be neater :) but still you'd better use enumerate too.

Comment: Yeah, `enumerate()` is always an option.

Comment: @SeiwonPark  This does not work if the last character in the string is 'x'

Comment: @Cobra ohhh yeah I think the whole algorithm should be changed totally

Comment: @Cobra Edited right away :)

Answer (score 0):

The required output appears to be a list of tuples (except that the last value isn't a valid representation of a tuple)

You just need to enumerate the string and construct the tuples as you check the characters in the string.

Something like this:

```
string1= '0100xx11xxx0x1'

result = []
t = None

for i, c in enumerate(string1):
    if c == 'x':
        t = (t[0], i) if t else (i,)
    else:
        if t:
            t = result.append(t)

if t: # final check needed in case last character in string is 'x'
    result.append(t)
    
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
[(4, 5), (8, 10), (12,)]
```